# reference non plugin project to eclipse plugin project

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Can I add a reference from an eclipse plugin project to a non plugin jar?
This is a jar that I can not change, so i have to use it as is.

Thank you
Ido

Answer (score 2):

The safest approach would be to create a new plugin from your existing jar file:

Select **New project -> Plug-In Development -> Plug-in from existing JAR Archives**

Then choose the jar file(s) ('**Add Externals**' on Galileo), name the project and fill in some plug-in properties (optional) and choose whether you want to unzip the jar or keep it as it is. I keep the checkbox checked...

And that's it. Eclipse will autogenerate a plugin project that exports all packages so that it can be used in your plug-in or rcp project.

Comment: Each client of my plugin have this jar on his computer, and i do not want him to have another copy, because the jar might update by the 3rd party.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is to add the jar to your plugin and modify the classpath.

Copy the jar into a sub-directory of the plugin (e.g. lib), then modify the plugin's classpath (in the manifest editor) to include the plugin root and lib/foo.jar.

In the Manifest Editor, select the **Runtime** tab and select the **Add** button on the Classpath pane. Add the jar, e.g. "lib/foo.jar" and select OK, if you look at the manifest source you should see a line like:

```
Bundle-ClassPath: lib/foo.jar,
 .
```

If the jar is to be used by other plugins, you can configure the manifest to export the packages in the nested jar, then other plugins can add a dependency to the containing plugin and use it as normal. To do so go to the **Runtime** tab of the Manifest editor, select **Add..** on the **Exported Packages** section, then select all the packages to be exported. If you look at the manifest you should see all the packages listed like this:

```
Export-Package: name.seller.rich,
 name.seller.rich.junit,
 name.seller.rich.foo,
 ...
```

Comment: it's 200 mb of jar files... i wanted to add it as variables

Comment: For it to be used by Eclipse a jar either needs to be nested in a plugin, or be a plugin. The only alternative would be for you to create a custom classloader to reference the jar, but then you'd still have to define a way to deliver the jar and ensure its in the right place. Much simpler to add it to a plugin and export all the packages.

Comment: This jar might be updated, and every user of my plug-in will have it on his computer. I do not want to supply it with my plug-in.

Comment: I've had a look around, I don't think you have much choice: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_can_I_share_a_JAR_among_various_plug-ins%3F

Comment: I have seen an interesting book about bundling by reference:
http://book.javanb.com/eclipse-rich-client-platform-designing-coding-and-packaging-java-applications-oct-2005/ch20lev1sec4.html

I still couldn't got it to work though...