# can eclipse plugin project depend on java project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have an eclipse plugin project which dependes on java project in my eclipse. usually what I did is export the project as jar and use it as-is in the plugin. but this requires manual work. can I have a reference from my plugin projct to a java project that will be both compile-time and run-time dependency ?
I saw a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184129/reference-non-plugin-project-to-eclipse-plugin-project), but not exactly the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, the closest thing to this is to create a jar file from the referenced project, and import it to the projects repository. But thats quite hard to manage for a currently developed project.

On the other hand, isn't it possible to simply convert the Java project into a plug-in permanently? If the other user does not use OSGi/Eclipse, he/she will see only a manifest/manifest.mf file (and possibly a plugin.xml) next to the java project specific stuff, so this would not disturb them, but would help you.

Comment: 1.will it have any effect if they are also working with eclipse? 2.can I use the new feature of eclipse of linking of eclipse to create another project with the same sources?

Comment: 1. They will see, that the project is also a plug-in project. But as this project does not have any external dependency, it will (or at least should) not cause any kind of problems for them. 2. I don't know, never tried such thing. It might work, but it is prone to break in my opinion.